# MVC optimization for Session.Clear(), Session.Abandon(), Session.RemoveAll()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am using a few sessions that should be terminated when the user is done.  I stumbled on these 3 session killers. When is the best time to use these as I use sessions more time than not.  Also, is there any other session termination I am not aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ASP.NET, when should I use Session.Clear() rather than Session.Abandon()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347377/in-asp-net-when-should-i-use-session-clear-rather-than-session-abandon)

Comment: As a duplicate... should I just remove this question?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Session.Clear` and `Session.RemoveAll` are identical; the latter just calls the former. They immediately remove all items stored in the session, but the session itself survives. Session_OnEnd does not fire.

`Session.Abandon` doesn't actually clear the values immediately, it just marks the session to be abandoned at the end of the current request. You can continue to read the values for the rest of the request. If you write to the session later in the request, the new value will be quietly discarded at the end of the request with no warning. Session_OnEnd fires at the end of the request, not when Abandon is called.

Comment: YOU SIR.. SAVED ME FROM KILLING MYSELF. I thought it's 'cool' to call `Session.Abandon()` at the start of my `Login` and then put the data in, if the login succeeds. Thank you for this. I can sleep now.

Answer (score 14):

`Session.Clear` does not kill a Session, it clears all values.  `Session.Abandon` actually kills the Session.

Looks like most of this is addressed here: [In ASP.NET, when should I use Session.Clear() rather than Session.Abandon()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347377/in-asp-net-when-should-i-use-session-clear-rather-than-session-abandon)

Comment: Nice!! Thanks... what about Session.RemoveAll()?

Answer (score 1):

Little late here but would like to share the proof that @stevemegson is correct as `Session.RemoveAll` internally calls `Session.Clear`

```
public void Clear()
        {
            this._container.Clear();
        }
        public void RemoveAll()
        {
            this.Clear();
        }
```

And so there is exactly no difference between at all

And `session.Abandon` calls

```
public void Abandon()
        {
            this._container.Abandon();
        }
```

which basically do :)..

```
public void Abandon()
{
    this._abandon = true;
}
```