# Session null in C# MVC

Tags: c#, session, model-view-controller

I want to make all sessions null in one statement when i make logout.Can anyone tell me how to make all session null.Currently i am making Sessions null as follows:

```
Session["UserID"]=null; 
Session["UserName"]=null; 
Session["Photo"]=null;
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer is probably in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551178/1220550

Comment: Just use `Session.Clear();` Easy to find if you describe your problem correctly: you do not want to make "sessions null", you want to reset all session variables.

Answer (score 0):

This example will do the job:

```
Session["UserID"] = "test1 value";
Session["UserName"] = "test2 value";
Session["Photo"] = "test3 value";

foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
     Session.Remove(key);
}

Response.Write(Session["UserID"]);
Response.Write(Session["UserName"]);
Response.Write(Session["Photo"]);
```

This could have been also done using linq, like here.

```
var sessionsToRemove = Session.Keys.Cast<string>().ToList();
foreach (var key in sessionsToRemove)
{
    Session.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: OR you could just call `Session.Clear()`.

Comment: Thank you for your precious response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
 session.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.