# Session killed but page is coming

Tags: c#, session, logout

I m using session in my project and i wrote

```
Session.Clear(); 
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

under the logout button. And i m cheking Session["user"] in all pages's page load event. if it is null i am sending user to Login.aspx. But pages are coming without go to page load event when i write a page to url however i clicked Logout button.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Çağın

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.Clear()` only clears values in session dictionary. Use `Session.Abandon()`.

[In ASP.NET, when should I use Session.Clear() rather than Session.Abandon()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347377/in-asp-net-when-should-i-use-session-clear-rather-than-session-abandon)

Comment: I wrote Session.Abandon() but my problem dosent solved. I can go the pages how i write page url on the url area and i m sure of cheking Sessions on the page load events.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Session.Abandon Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28VS.90%29.aspx)