# How to implement or configure hard session expiry in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config, timeout, session-state

I can set a 20 minutes timeout for the sessions which means if the user doesn't make a request within the 20 minutes period, his/her session expires.

```
<sessionState timeout="20" />
```

But what I need is to be able to expire the session after a certain time no matter the user is still sending requests.

For example, after 4 hours the session must be expired no matter the user sends another request or not; that's to prevent malwares to abuse the default session behaviour...

How to configure or implement it in ASP.NET?

I hoped there would be a config setting but I couldn't find one?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a code sample and exactly what I want:

http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-implement-hard-session-expiry-in.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration setting for this requirement as it is rather unique.

You can implement this by issuing a cookie to the client when it first connects - check this cookie on every request and start rejecting it when 4 hours have passed. You can either store this start time in a cookie or in a `Session` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Oded mention you should also store the first login time in session on session start event. and when you are reading the session check the time and use Session.Clear();

and easy way the check session start time access it using a global property.

```
public User CurrentUser
{
    get 
    {
         User user = (User)Session["CurrentUser"];
         if (user.startTime > "4 hours") // you can do it what ever you want.
             Session.Clear(); //or .Abandon(); [Check Here][1]

         return (User)Session["CurrentUser"]
    }
}
```

[Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347377/in-asp-net-when-should-i-use-session-clear-rather-than-session-abandon)