# Closing sessions while pressing on a link

Tags: asp.net

I want to close my session while pressing on the text in the list. I don't really know how to do it. It is ASP.net and its need to be when I press the last link.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a class="selected" href="AdminPage.aspx">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AdminRegels.aspx">Regels</a></li>
      <li><a href="AdminAfspr.aspx">Afspraken</a></li>
      <li><a href="AdminGrenzen.aspx">Grenzen</a></li>
      <li><a href="AdminUser.aspx">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Web/Home.aspx">Uitloggen</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want to close the window?  Or Clear out session variables?  Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you try using Session.Clear() on page_load of ../Web/Home.aspx. which will clear the session on link click.

Comment: i want to clear the session variables

Answer (score 0):

The user would click on the `AdminPage.aspx` link and then you can clear the session in the Page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // clear or abandon ...
}
```

It's not clear whether you want to use Session.Clear or Abandon. See the following SO answer on which one is suitable for your requirement.

[In ASP.NET, when should I use Session.Clear() rather than Session.Abandon()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347377/in-asp-net-when-should-i-use-session-clear-rather-than-session-abandon)